# What is Pakistan's position on Eastern Ladakh/Aksai Chin?

Tags: china, india, pakistan, territorial-dispute, kashmir

Eastern Ladakh/Aksai Chin is a Himalayan Region.

It is administered by China since they won the 1962 Sino-Indian war.
However, it is claimed by India as a part of the Union Territory of Ladakh (within the erstwhile Jammu and Kashmir state). Pakistan also claims J&K's territory.

What's the position of Pakistan on the Eastern Ladakh/Aksai Chin issue? Do they claim that region as well, or they support the Chinese administration?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I realize, this is an open issue between Pakistan and China.

[image]

If you look at the latest updated map of Pakistan [released during Imran Khan's regime](https://www.dawn.com/news/1572590), the boundary between Kashmir and China has not been shown. The map was released after consulting the Chinese embassy in Islamabad.

That means the solution to this problem isn't decided yet.

That is, if Pakistan ever gets hold of Kashmir, this problem will be resolved through negotiations as was in Shaksgam Valley's case.